# Node.js > open a .csv file in readonly mode while writing data to the file

Tags: node.js, csv, electron, fs

I am using `Node.Js` filesystem to write data to `.csv` file. If I open the file when the write operation is still incomplete, it's causing the loss of data because `fs` is unable to write when the file is open. So is there any way to open the file in `read-only` mode if the write operation is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been resolved when I used `fs.createWriteStream` for the file operation.